# How to rotate Object3D in three.js around own center by TransformControls

Tags: three.js, rotation, transform

I want to rotate `Object3D`(it's mesh group) by `TransformControls`.
So I attached `TransformControls` to `Object3D` and set position of `TransformControls`  to `Object3D`'s center.

**Here is tried code:**

```
let transformControl = new THREE.TransformControls(viewer.camera, viewer.canvas);
transformControl.setMode("rotate");
transformControl.setSpace("local");

let meshGroup = new THREE.Group();

// here I added lot of mesh to meshGroup.
............ 

let bbox = new THREE.Box3();
bbox.setFromObject(meshGroup);
let center = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
center = bbox.getCenter(center);
center.sub(meshGroup.position);
transformControl.position.set(center.x, center.y, center.z);
transformControl.attach(meshGroup);
```

But when I tried rotation with use `TransformControls`, `Object3D` rotate around world axis instead his own center.
How can I fix it?
Please anyone help.

**PS**: I don't want move position of meshGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I solved the centering problem by shifting object positions.

Take a look at the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-issue-66014353-typescript-transform-control-centering?file=index.ts). I created this sample without knowing what framework/library you used but I made it in typescript.

Comment: I've tried with your method. but it's not working for me. because the position of mesh is different to original position. Is there any method without change position of mesh?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the solution as your answer. [Links should never be the only piece of information in your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/392254)

Comment: I read the source code of TransformControls and in my opinion you can't perform such operation because there are internal variable that makes rotate the mesh only from his origin without allow you to set any external offset or similar. I guess you need to consider to use an offset. In my case I apply the offset after loading coordinates from a local configuration.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, Could you make change to TransformControls for rotate his own center?

Comment: Any suggestion for fix TransformControls? I will change code of TransformControls if need.

Comment: If you mind to apply some change I would suggest to add your code after "// Apply rotate" comment. In that point you can apply your rotation implementation. In my stackblitz I added some uncompleted examples in fileTransformControls2.ts for give you an idea.
In any case, the implementation of your custom rotation should be done in all rotation axes.